# UV stretching when subdividing - how to avoid

Tags: uv, subdivision-surface

I made a mesh with a decent topology, gave it a subdivision **before** UVing and UVed it after. Even still, when I subdivide it again **after** UVing I get some very ugly distortions on my checker textures. How to avoid this sort of issue? Frankly the mesh hardly shifts shape when I smooth, and even still the distortion is disgusting.

**Edit:** 
[image]

Comment: Which tool or operator are you using to subdivide?

Comment: Just added a subdivision surface mod, using catmull-clarke

Comment: Could you upload it here (or at least part of your mesh, but with textures packed)? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Of course, hold on a sec...

Comment: Strange, when I export, the UVs become ugly af. I try setting the checker textures's tiling
EDIT: got it working, forgot to add the texture coordinate :D exporting now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler example to see what is happening here:

[image]

Now we add a loop cut on the conic part:

[image]

And if the loop cuts were on the cylinder part:

[image]

In both cases, the proportions are respected in the mesh point of view. But the vertices which are displaced by the subsurface modifier are not at the same position in the UV map. So, they are not kept in place (relatively) the same way.

... a bit hard to explain... but I hope this example is enough to get the point.

In your model, cuts are mainly on the equivalent of the cylinder part here, plus, some are in the cylinder part and others in the conic part (the seam is mixed). So you have distortions.

Comment: So at the end I just need some edge loops to minimize the distortion?

Comment: Yes... doing it, use 'correct UV' in the operator options

Answer (score 2):

instead of adding additional loops, you can just go into edit mode, select the boundary between two materials, press shift + E and then press 1 to turn up crease weight for that edge.  It'll also cause a sharp edge though, so probably not ideal on a curved surface.  In that instance you'd probably need to apply the subdivision modifier and possibly do the uv unwrap again.